# refresh select element after X seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to refresh a dropdown select after X seconds,
currently the dropdown submits a form onChange. 
the browser prompts a download/save as alert.
I would like the dropdown to return to value="0", after the first onChange/formsubmit.

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="csv_export" name="csv_export" onchange="this.form.submit()">

            <option value="0"
                    data-content="<i class='fa fa-cloud-download'></i><span class='hidden-sm'> Export as  </span>"></option>
            <option data-icon="fa fa-file-excel-o" style="background: #5cb85c; color: #fff;"
                    value="1"
                    data-content="<i class='fa fa-file-excel-o'></i><span class='hidden-sm'> CSV  </span>"></option>
```

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(
            function() {
                setInterval(function() {

                    $('#csv_export').append('<option value="0"></option>');
                }, 3000);
            });
   </script>
```

Comment: if the form submits then the page will reload right??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply set the `select` back to the first option you want

```
$('#csv_export').val('0');
```

not to append a new `option` which is what your code currently does.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(
        function() {
            setInterval(function() {

                $('#csv_export').html('<option value="0">-select-</option>');
            }, 3000);
        });
```

this works